# Two process in one Heroku app vs two heroku apps

Tags: django, heroku, django-celery, worker, procfile

I have a heroku app, that has two processes - a web and a worker, both in the same app. I plan to run both these in ps:scale 1x for the whole month. This essentially means that I exceed the 750 free dyno hours per month and have to pay some fees.

**One app, two processes**

*App*

- web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi --log-file -
- worker: celery -A myproject worker -B -E -l info -c 1

I was thinking of splitting them into two separate apps, the web and the worker having their own apps, and communicating via REST API between themselves. Since these are two apps, each of them would respectively be as below. This way both apps would be under 750 hours respectively and won't have a charge.

**Two app, each with one processes**

*App1*

- web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi --log-file -

*App2*

- worker: celery -A myproject worker -B -E -l info -c 1

**What are the pros and cons of doing this over the first approach? Thanks**

Comment: any answers for this please? Or should I be posting with different tags?

Comment: Not sure, but your tags look right. It's a very specific question; that may be the problem. I'd also like to see an answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the only **Pro** to this approach is the cost savings, the **cons** are having to jump through hoops to communicate over the REST API.